# Cannot add a view in another view

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, mvvm

I am new to XAML and MVVM. I am trying to follow this demo 
[How do I use MVVM in a windows phone 7 application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg241309) 
. The problem I am facing is that when in my MainPage.xaml I try to point towards another view and do something like

```
xmlns:view="clr-namespace:MyMVVM.View"
..
..
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <view:CustomerView x:Name="Customers" DataContext="{Binding Path = CustomerView}">
    </view:CustomerView>
</Grid>
```

then i see an error message as

> Element is already the child of another element

Comment: It seems that the project from the link you gave us works and runs properly. What other issues does this error cause you besides just showing up on the error list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is just an error from the designer but will not prevent it from running. If you want to fix the error in the designer, you could easily just replace phone:PhoneApplicationPage by UserControl and rebuild and the designer error should disapear.